# json file downloading and reading windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8-sdk

hi i am new in windows phone development currently i am working on online application but.i have a problem that how to download a json file from a url and store it into local storage as text file and again how to read the text from it to perform parsing.

using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if(isf.FileExists("file.txt"))
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream rawstream = isf.OpenFile("file.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(rawstream);
                        result = read.ReadLine();
                        read.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("completed and readed " + result);
            }

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is download a json then parse it.

**to download a json file**

```
private void GetAlbums()
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(dataFeed, UriKind.Absolute);
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AlbumsDownloaded);
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

**To parse and read this file**

```
  public void AlbumsDownloaded(object sender,   DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
        // Deserialize JSON string to dynamic object
        IDictionary<string, object> json = (IDictionary<string, object>)SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(e.Result);
        // Feed object
        IDictionary<string, object> feed = (IDictionary<string, object>)json["feed"];
}
```

I found this article very helpful. You should take an hour to go through this sample to make your life easier.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Picasa_Image_Gallery_with_JSON_in_WP7